# Python Selenium preventing "Show All Downloads" message appearing

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, download, profile

First time posting here; I'll do my best to follow the rules. I haven't been able to find an up to date answer to my question anywhere on any site.
I'm trying to automatically download a PDF with Selenium, Python, Firefox, and a Raspberry Pi. The downloading works, but while I can disable the "Open/ Save As" window, I can't seem to disable the "Download Completed/ Show All Downloads" window. Here is the snippet of relevant code assembled from all the failed answers I've found:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/Desktop/ff_profile.default')

profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/home/pi/Desktop')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.panel.shown', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.hide_plugins_without_extensions', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete', False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.animateNotifications", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.saveLinkAsFilenameTimeout", 0)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.retention", 0)
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get(url)
```

I believe the problem lies with a lot of these options recently getting removed from about:config but haven't found a workaround. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your firefox is 98.0 or after, please use

profile.set_preference("browser.download.alwaysOpenPanel", False)